# Streaming with nginx (smooth streaming)

Tags: nginx, streaming, video-streaming

I am interested in video streaming, but I have a problem.

I have tried to use `http_flv_module` combined with  `http_secure_link_module` that is great, but I  have found that nginx has an alternative called `nginx-rtmp-module`.

I need to do something to stream video in small content fragments 
to offer more options like changing resolution and enabling computers with lower bandwidth to to view it.

My question is, is there any solution for Smooth Streaming with the `nginx`  server ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this module will get you what you're looking for:

http://h264.code-shop.com/trac/wiki/Mod-Smooth-Streaming-Nginx-Version1

Comment: i have seen this module but i have never tried out i will try it